# Rails 4 Carrierwave image not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am new to Stackoverflow and am learning Ruby on Rails, using Carrierwave for image uploading. I am creating a contacts book and having issues when updating multiple images at once. In the new contact form I have it set up so that the user can add multiple comma separated contacts and a check box if the user wants to add images. The problem that I am having is when the user has multiple new contacts and wants to add images the images are not uploading, every other case is working fine. Here is my controller, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.find(session[:group_id])
    @contacts = []
    redirect_path = nil
    render_path = nil

    if ",".in? contact_params[:name]
       #create multiple contact objects in @contacts array
      @strings = contact_params[:name].split(/,/)
      @strings.count.times do
        @contacts << Contact.new
      end
      @contacts.each_with_index do |contact, index|
        contact.name = @strings[index].strip
        contact.user = current_user
        contact.group_id = @group.id
        if contact.save
          flash[:success] = "Saved"
          redirect_path = group_path(@group)
        else
          flash[:danger] = "Failed to save"
          redirect_path = edit_multiple_contacts_path(@contacts)
        end
      end
      if params[:cbox] == "true"
         #need to go to edit multiple
        redirect_path = nil
        render_path = 'edit_multiple'
      else
       #do nothing
      end
    else
      @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
      @contact.user = current_user
      @contact.group_id = @group.id
      if @contact.save
         #flash[:success] = "Saved"
        redirect_path = group_path(@group)
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Failed to save"
      end

      if params[:cbox] == "true"
        redirect_path = edit_contact_path(@contact)
      else
        #do nothing
      end
    end

    if redirect_path.nil?
      render render_path
    else
      redirect_to(redirect_path)
    end
  end # end of create

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @group = Group.find(session[:group_id])
    @contact.destroy
    flash[:success] = "This contact has been removed"
    redirect_to group_path(@group)
  end

  def update
    @group = Group.find(session[:group_id])
    if @contact.update(contact_params)
      flash[:success] = "#{@contact.name} has been updated"
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit_multiple
  end

  def update_multiple
    @group = Group.find(session[:group_id])
    @contacts = Contact.update(params[:contacts].keys,   params[:contacts].values)
    @contacts.reject! { |u| u.errors.empty? }
    if @contacts.empty?
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    else
      render 'edit_multiple'
    end
  end #end update_multiple


private

  def set_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :image, :contacts)
  end

end
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding ":multipart => true" to the form_tag in the html.erb